# Python - Readline and compare

Tags: python

Im trying to create a function which reads each line in a file and compares the words with their reverse (palindrome) version `i.e > (heheh = heheh) & (law = wal)`. So when i tried to do that the condition has failed and the function returned an empty list.

**CODE**

```
def palindrome_lst():
    lst = []
    with open("words.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line == line[::-1]:
                lst.append(line)
    return lst

print palindrome_lst()
```

Comment: Do you want to compare words or lines? You mentioned that you wish to compare words, but you're comparing the whole line.

Comment: Can you also post the input file?

Comment: @SilentMonk
its just some random words bro:

efe
sefe
wefew
lala
lol
doge
come
emoc
blackwolf
wolf
wolw
volv
volvo
jebote
etobej
kurwa
awruk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When iterating over the lines in a file, you're getting the line-terminator along with the rest of the line. Id est, you're not comparing `"eye" == "eye"`, but `"eye\n" == "\neye"`, which is of course false for all words.

Try adding `line = line.strip()` before the comparison.